# Apache Mod Rewrite for Pretty URLs isn't working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to do an apache `mod_rewrite` to remap `$_GET`.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

Currently, to get to the page one would have to go to

`http://www.domain.com/index.php?URL=pages/the-page.php`

**I would like this to work in 2 ways:**

If someone goes to `domain.com/the-page`, it takes them to the above but keeps it looking like this. Secondly, if someone goes to the `http://www.domain.com/index.php?URL=pages/the-page.php`, it will still show as `domain.com/the-page`, keeping the URL short and clean.

**Most Recently Tried Code**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} URL=pages/([a-z0-9-_]+)\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1
```

I'm pretty sure I setup everything right in the apache `httpd.conf`. I'm using XAMPP to test locally, restarted apache on changes, still nothing. Where am I going wrong?

***I would prefer to handle this in .htaccess***

I am using XAMPP localhost and trying on live server.

**Log File:**

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:16:50:43 --0400] [localhost/sid#2f3140][rid#3b14068/initial] (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/index.php -> index.php`

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:16:50:43 --0400] [localhost/sid#2f3140][rid#3b14068/initial] (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri 'index.php'`

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:16:50:43 --0400] [localhost/sid#2f3140][rid#3b14068/initial] (1) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/index.php`

**Updated log with Olaf's script *(last rule commented out)***

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:20:02:24 --0400] [localhost/sid#2e3140][rid#3b14090/initial] (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/index.php -> index.php`

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:20:02:24 --0400] [localhost/sid#2e3140][rid#3b14090/initial] (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'`

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:20:02:24 --0400] [localhost/sid#2e3140][rid#3b14090/initial] (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/index.php -> index.php`

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:20:02:24 --0400] [localhost/sid#2e3140][rid#3b14090/initial] (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri 'index.php'`

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:20:02:24 --0400] [localhost/sid#2e3140][rid#3b14090/initial] (2) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] rewrite 'index.php' -> '/newhome?'`

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:20:02:24 --0400] [localhost/sid#2e3140][rid#3b14090/initial] (3) split uri=/newhome? -> uri=/newhome, args=<none>`

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:20:02:24 --0400] [localhost/sid#2e3140][rid#3b14090/initial] (2) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://localhost/newhome` ***<--this one seems to be causing the issue***

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:20:02:24 --0400] [localhost/sid#2e3140][rid#3b14090/initial] (1) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] escaping http://localhost/newhome for redirect`

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2013:20:02:24 --0400] [localhost/sid#2e3140][rid#3b14090/initial] (1) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/cdi/] redirect to http://localhost/newhome [REDIRECT/302]`

Thank you everyone that is helping. I've spent 2 days trying to get this to work!!!

Comment: Is this still your current and complete .htaccess?

Comment: No, but I have commented out the httpd.conf code I added and removed all .htaccess except for the code below as instructed.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If it is just rewriting an incoming request from `/abc` to `/index.php?URL=pages/abc.php`, then remove the `RewriteCond`. The `RewriteRule` alone should work as it is.

Comment: Updated original question.

Comment: I just answered a similar question, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15839460/1741542

Comment: I think you have a configuration problem but not in the _.htaccess_. Can you link your real website here?

Comment: I'm a bit leery to post it here in it's current state (needs a security audit first). The httpd.conf is now stock (had to uninstall/reinstall when server was caught in loop). `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">` has proper permissions (All) so .htaccess can do what it likes. Is there somewhere else to look? Olaf's rewrite is somewhat working... shows correct URL to client, but not to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need two rules. One rule to redirect the client to a clean URL and another to internally rewrite the pretty URL to the real content via `index.php`.

Assuming the `index.php` and `.htaccess` is in a directory `cdi`

```
RewriteEngine on

# prevent endless loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect the client
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} URL=pages/(.+?)\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /cdi/%1? [R,L]

# exclude rewriting all files located in /cdi/files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cdi/files/
# rewrite to real content
RewriteRule ^.*$ /cdi/index.php?URL=pages/$0.php [L]
```

**Update**:

When the request is `/cdi/index.php?URL=pages/abc.php`, the second rule extracts the needed `URL` part and redirects the client to the new URL path. The client then requests the new URL `/cdi/abc` and the third rule takes this and does an internal rewrite to the real content.

This all works fine as it should, but would rewrite and redirect indefinitely. To break this endless rule, the first rule checks the environment `%{ENV:...}`, if the request was already redirected `REDIRECT_STATUS` and then stops the cycle with the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

which matches everything `^` and does no [substitution](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rhs), but ends the rewrite cycle with the flag [`[L]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

Instead of using the system provided environment `STATUS`/`REDIRECT_STATUS`, you can also set a variable yourself with the flag [`E=SEO:1`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e) for example, and then test for this variable with

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SEO} 1
```

For the `REDIRECT_` prefix, see [Available Variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html#variables).

Comment: Oh my God it actually did something!!! Fist one to even remotely change the URL. Unfortunately, it's printing like this `http://localhost/subfolder/the-page?URL=pages/subfolder/the-page.php`

Comment: By the way, what's up with the `$0`? I thought the backpath started at `$1`.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE I forgot to add a question mark `?` at the end of the rule. Please see updated answer. `$0` is the whole pattern, `$1` is the first group `(...)`, `$2` the second `(...)` and so on.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying. On the live server, the URL shows up perfectly! Unfortunately, it reports a 404 error :(. *I was able to get it to work on localhost by commenting out the bottom rule (though it reads `localhost/subfolder/the-page` instead of `localhost/site/subfolder/the-page`), and breaks the site.* The rewrite to real content doesn't seem to be working for me on the live server.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE So, it redirects the client to the correct pretty URL, but it doesn't display the page? How should the real URL look like?

Comment: like the first example in original post. That's the actual path.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE Then I don't understand why it gives a 404 error. What is this `site` subdirectory? Can you see in the error log what's going wrong?

Comment: Wasn't aware subdirectories mattered using .htaccess
On localhost, it's `localhost/cdi`
On the live server, `.com/new`
I'll re-enable rewrite log and report back.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE Subdirectories matter, when the substitution is an absolute URL. Are both the `index.php` and `.htaccess` file in the `cdi`/`new` subdirectory?

Comment: Yes. Wouldn't it stay a relative path since the domain isn't specified? I'm hoping this works across all of my sites.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE I removed the leading slash. Try with the relative URL. Most of the time, this works without problems.

Comment: Hmm.. how can I add a subfolder (i.e. cdi in `localhost/cdi/the-page`) to the last rule? The rest seems to be working great.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE You can just insert it at the appropriate places. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Ah missed the 1st cdi. How odd.. here's what it's doing. With the previous version, if I manually added cdi, it went to the page! Now that it's showing the correct 'pretty path', it returns 404! This is so strange...

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE I just fixed the last `RewriteRule`. I forgot, that the leading `cdi` is stripped by mod_rewrite, when in a directory context. Now it should redirect `/cdi/index.php?URL=pages/abc.php` to `/cdi/abc` and rewrite back again.

Comment: Ah tried updated code with 1 cdi. It actually loads the page! Thank you for that. The only problem now is that it's messing up the linked files (stylesheets, scripting). When I click them in the source code, it just starts combining the paths in the URL but it keeps showing the main source code instead of the linked file's code.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE Depending on where these are located, you must add some `RewriteCond`s to the last `RewriteRule` to prevent rewriting them. Are these located in some subdirectory?

Comment: Hmm.. that would either be only redirect `PHP|HTML` or completely exclude rewrites for the folder `files`.. or would placing this .htaccess in the `pages` folder fix it all together? Currently in "root" (cdi)

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE I added a `RewriteCond` to prevent rewriting `/cdi/files/*`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you SO much, this has been a huge help in understanding the magic that is mod_rewrite. Hopefully this helps others as well (I've seen a lot of questions similar to this without answers). You the man Olaf.

Comment: Why is the remapping `RewriteRule` rules `.* /cdi/$var` instead of `.* /$var`? Is this because the `/index.php` file is located in the `/cdi/` folder?

Comment: @Servant Correct. `.*` is without `/cdi`. `/$0` would therefore try to request it in the root folder and not in `cdi`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I really like your answer, specially the `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200` and `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`. Could you please explain what's the `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` and its complete output, *(ex. the sample output of %{REQUEST_URI} is /this/that.htm,)* and the `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`? What's this `-`? You can also give a link for that.

Comment: @Servant I tried to explain a bit more thoroughly, what the rules are doing. Please see updated answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929517/mod-rewrite-is-not-including-subdirectories Care to lend a hand again?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9_-]{1,40})/?$ index.php?URL=pages/$1.php
```

Though ideally you might want to get rid of the "pages/" part of the query string variable, as this fixed constant could be handled by the index.php script.

Comment: Note : `[a-z0-9_]` is equal to `[\w]`, so `[a-z0-9_-]` can be compressed into `[\w-]`

Comment: I've edited the code because I've just realised you're using httpd.conf and not a local .htaccess file, so a forward-slash is needed at the start of the regex pattern after the `^` symbol.

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this to work. I've tried several combinations. Also, I'm doing this in .htaccess (tried both codes)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the group `([0-9]+)` to be alphabetic then just change it to `([a-z]+)` and if you've wanted it to be alphanumeric, then change it to `([a-z0-9]+)`, and `([a-z0-9-_]+)` if with a hyphen and an underscore. If you've wanted it to set their limits manually, you can do that with this format `([a-z0-9-_]{1,40})`. Do you see, the plus sign is gone, for it limited the `[chars]` with 1 to anything, and the `{1,40}` limited the `[chars]` with 1 to 40, you can either change it.

---

Do you know what the real problem is? Is my stress.. Imagine even I know that you want to remap */$var* into */index.php?URL=pages/$var.php* I'm still trying giving you a wrong information that will rewrite */index.php?URL=pages/$var.php* into */$var*. I just have realize that after my 4 hours sleep. Did you see what's happening when the time of your sleep isn't right? Maybe a rule I would gives to you when my brain's in functioning well, was:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?URL=pages/$1.php
```

Why did the viewers letting this to happened.. My previous codes are needed to be voted down.

Comment: Those both make more sense from what I've been reading, but for some reason it still isn't working. I do 302 redirects all the time in .htaccess, but I haven't had a single rewrite to work. Engine is loaded and on, even following symlinks. Maybe I should try to do this within a directory in the httpd.conf of Apache?

Comment: Those codes are intended for _.htaccess_ file. However, you can still try it in other file. Have you ever tried the code itself with just `Options +FollowSymlinks` and `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: Yes, and I have tried placing the above in the .htaccess of `/pages`, still no luck. Also tried locally and on live server. I would rather use .htaccess, as one of my clients has a very restrictive shared host.

Comment: Do you mean is to remap the _domain.com/$var_ into the _domain.com/index.php?URL=pages/$var.php_

Comment: I'm trying to remove everything except what follows `pages/`. I'd like to get rid of the .php extention as well. Updated original code with log info.

Answer (score 0):

You approach seems fine but **your `RewriteCond` doesn't match** your requirements:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php?URL=pages
```

means "rewrite the URL if someone requests something that starts with 'index.php"—but that's not what anyone will be requesting. You want your visitors to request pretty URLs.

If your server only needs to serve those requests for /the-page, you can drop the condition entirely. Then any URL will be rewritten. (Note: This might not be what you want!)

Otherwise, the condition should read something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[a-z0-9-_]{1,40}
```

If you don't want to mess with regular expressions, you could also try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

which means "if the user requests a URL for which no file can be found, rewrite the URL according to the upcoming `RewriteRule`."

Comment: excited to see the `RewriteRule`. I'm beginning to understand regular expressions. I've read over the docs several times.