# Getting a 500 with mod_rewrite due to infinite redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to have

> **`http://test.domain.net/2a`**

to be processed as

> **`http://test.domain.net/?i=2a`**

I'm getting a 500 error due to infinite redirects. Where is my rule going wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?i=$1
```

Comment: You can prevent the endless loop with an appropriate `RewriteCond`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15843806/1741542 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /?i=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @paranoid-android The problem you were having before was that your rules were looping. Mod_rewrite will continue to loop through all the rules until the URI stops changing. Since the target of your rule (`/`, query string is not included) matches the pattern `^([^/]*)$`, it'll continue to be applied. The 2 conditions simply check that if the URI maps to an existing file or directory, then don't apply the rule at all.