# Mod_rewrite is not including subdirectories

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a mod_rewrite (mostly thanks to stack member Olaf) that redirects from 
`index.php?URL=pages/the-page.php` to simply `the-page`. The problem is, when a page is requested that isn't directly in `pages` (i.e., `pages/sub`), it redirects my .css and .js which is no good.

**What I'm trying to accomplish is this:**

- ONLY rewrite files in the `pages` folder, but include ALL subdirectores of it.

An important thing is that it never, ever, ever rewrites the URL of the `files` folder.

Here's the code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
# prevent endless loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect the client
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} URL=pages/(.+?)\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /gr/%1? [R,L]

# exclude rewriting all files located in /gr/files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gr/files/
# rewrite to real content
RewriteRule ^.*$ /gr/index.php?URL=pages/$0.php [L]
```

I've spent countless hours fighting with this code. Even minor changes throws it to a 404 or 500 error.

*It also kills external links* making it .com/www instead of the appropriate address, which is a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it, but maybe excluding all real files with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mess with the mod_rewrite rules for the CSS and scripts. This sounds like a relative URI issue. Either change your links to be absolute URI's:

From:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
```

or whatever the absolute path to "style.css" is.

If you don't want to change all of your links, then add a URI base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Wasn't trying to rewrite those files. +1 for `<base href="/">`, fixed everything instantly.