# How do I rewrite and use only one version of the url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^first-test-page/?$ testing.php?idPage=1 [NC,L]
```

How do I redirect the user to domain.com/first-test-page/ if he goes to domain.com/testing.php?idPage=1 ?

Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15843806/1741542 for an example on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a two rules. This should work for you. Give this a try.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /+testing\.php\?idPage=1
RewriteRule ^ /first-test-page? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^first-test-page/?$ /testing.php?idPage=1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: ++ probably both `RewriteCond` are not needed.

Comment: true, it's habit when doing rewrites. It won't hurt though.

Comment: works! chrome didn't update in the first place, but edge says that it works! thanks!